# Why does a nested custom view inside of a ListView prevent proper focusing when the device is horizontal in android?

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a ListView with an adapter with custom Views. Each of the custom Views has an EditText. When I turn my device horizontally, everything loses focus, and when I try to focus on an EditText View the keyboard shows for a split second and then disappears, and everything loses focus. Why does this happen? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You can fix it by saving the focused view before rotating the device, and let it become the focused view again when it turns to landscape mode.